# Error: Servlet Jar not Loaded... Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Tags: java, tomcat, dependencies

I get the following error:

> INFO: validateJarFile(C:\dev\server\tomcat6\webapps
>   Sempedia\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, sectoin 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

The existing resources out there say it is due to a conflict with the servlet.jar or in my case named servlet-api.jar file. I have removed all other projects from the /webapps folder, I have taken the servlet-api.jar file that was in the tomcat6/lib directory and added that and only that to the project build path, so I can't see how there is still a conflict.

When I try to run the application I get the following stack trace.

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

> An error occurred at line: 22 in the generated java file
>   The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
>       org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Comment: If it's relevant I am using the servlet-api.jar file from a location that looks like this .../WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api.jar not .../tomcat6/lib/servlet-api.jar

Answer (score 40):

This is a sign of classpath pollution. The JSP/Servlet API libraries are appserver implementation dependent and belongs in case of Tomcat 6 in the `Tomcat/lib` folder and should in **no way** be moved nor duplicated somewhere else. It's recipe for portability trouble and collisions in classloading as you've encountered now. The libraries in webapp have precedence in classloading. If the `servlet-api.jar` is encountered there, it is in turn looking for its dependencies there, but they were apparently missing in there.

You must remove any appserver-specific libraries from the webapp's `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib`. You should *only* put webapp-specific libraries in there. Keep appserver-specific libraries in the appserver's own default classpath, which is the `Tomcat/lib` in your case. Keep it untouched. You can at most add libraries which you'd like to share among all webapps in there, or even better, configure the `shared.loader` in `Tomcat/conf/catalina.properties` for that.

Also remove any appserver-specific and webapp-specific libraries from the `JDK/lib` and `JRE/lib` folders, if any. I've seen too often that some starters move/copy the libraries there because "it otherwise doesn't compile". You should never copy non-JRK/JRE-specific libraries in there. It is recipe for portability trouble as well. When compiling classes with `javac`, you should use the `-cp` argument to specify the dependent libraries.

**Update**: in case of an IDE (you seem to use one as you're talking about "build path"), you need to associate the web project with an application server. In Eclipse for example, you have the option to do that during creation of a *Dynamic Web Project*. You need to integrate the server instance in Eclipse prior to project creation. You can do that through the `Servers` view (assuming that you're using *Eclipse for Java **EE** developers*, else upgrade). You can also change it afterwards through the *Servers* entry in the project properties. Choose one which you'd like to use as the "default" server and then its libraries will automagically be included in the project's build path. There's absolutely no need to copy/move them somewhere else. See also [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

Comment: Assuming that you mean that you still get the same problem, then you need to ensure that you cleanup the classpath as I explained in the first three paragraphs of my answer.

Answer (score 20):

As other answers say, this is because your WAR includes the servlet API classes, but it should not do so.

If you are using Maven to build your project you will want to tell Maven to make the servlet API available when compiling and testing, but not to include it in the WAR. As the [Maven documentation about dependency scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) says, you should use `provided` scope for the Servlet API:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

You might also have to explicitly exclude the Servlet API as a transitive dependency, if some of your dependencies pull in the Servlet API as a compile dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>frob-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How do I know if a dependency pulls in the servlet API?

Answer (score 4):

You are not allowed to deploy classes that override those defined in the Servlet Specification to be provided by the web container.   You can download the specification from

http://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr053/

and check for yourself.   Section 9.7.2 is on physical page 63.

Servlet 2.3 is a rather old version indicating an ancient version of Tomcat.  Is there any particular reason you are not using a newer one?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but I am using Java 6. Is the servlet spec going to be independent of this. You see the code was written by another group and I am trying to deploy the application so maybe the did something that is causing it to use Servlet spec 2.3 ? Not sure if this makes sense.

Comment: Yes.  Java is aggressively backwards compatible.  You most likely can just remove the servlet.jar from WEB-INF/lib as they probably left it in by mistake or ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

The first error message you got was because Tomcat doesn't need to load the servlet jar because it already has one and wants to avoid conflicts.

You can usually safely ignore the warning. If you don't want it to appear, you need to move the servlet jar from your project, rather than using the one from tomcat. By taking the tomcat one and putting it into your project, you've managed to convince tomcat to load it from your webapp rather than from from where it was expecting it, causing a classloader issue as mentioned in the BalusC's answer.

Edit: The above was edited to clarify what was happening once you put the servlet-api jar from tomcat into your webapp (and attribute BalusC).

Comment: The second stacktrace is definitely an error. The first one is an INFO message. It may be a problem in this case but I've seen this before in projects that I've deployed and Tomcat has merrily continued after ignoring the jar.

Comment: Ah okay, an info message is still not a warning message :)

Comment: Haha, yeah, ok. How about we call it a draw :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact I had such error and app. wasn't able to get started, because for some reason, some of the jars in `WEB-INF/lib` had **`.JAR`** (upper case) extension instead of `.jar`. So make sure that all the jars are valid.

Answer (score 0):

*Exclusions and `provided` dependencies will not work in child projects.*

If you are using inheritance in Maven projects you *must* include this configuration on the parent `pom.xml` file. You  will have a `<parent>...</parent>` section in your pom.xml *if you are using inheritance*. So you will have something like this in your parent `pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>some.groupId</groupId>
<version>1.0</version>
<artifactId>someArtifactId</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>child-module-1</module>
    <module>child-module-2</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```