# Deploying a gwtp maven app: See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Tags: maven, gwt, gwtp

Using the directions at https://github.com/ArcBees/ArcBees-tools/blob/master/archetypes/gwtp-basic/README.md and http://c.gwt-examples.com/home/maven/ide-import/eclipse  I've created a GWTP project with maven.  It works well on the debug mode but I'm having problems deploying it.

1) run the command mvn gwt:compile
2) copy the .war file to two different Tomcat servers
3) Restart the server
4) Browse to the location of the file and I get a 404 error

HTTP Status 404 - /transpohubAdmin/Project.html
type Status report
message /transpohubAdmin/Project.html
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.32

This error occurs also if I go directly to a css file (unless I delete the Project.html file first)

The catalina.out is:

```
May 2, 2013 9:22:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/transpohubAdmin.war
May 2, 2013 9:22:02 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/Library/Tomcat/webapps/transpohubAdmin/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-user-2.5.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
May 2, 2013 9:22:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 2, 2013 9:22:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/transpohubAdmin] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I've googled See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class and not found any help with this error.

Any suggestions?

Cheers,

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993493/error-servlet-jar-not-loaded-offending-class-javax-servlet-servlet-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have `gwt-user` in your WAR. There should be `gwt-servlet` if your use GWT-RPC, or `requestfactory-server` if you use RequestFactory.

In other words, the `gwt-user` dependency in the `pom.xml` should have `<scope>provided</scope>` and you should add a dependency on `gwt-servlet` with `<scope>runtime</scope>`.

Please file an issue on Brandon's archetype.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I'll file that issue.