# validating jar file error in eclipse while starting tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

validate jar file (link to hidden metadata folder in my working directory/geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

I am getting this error message while starting tomcat from eclipse and it is leading me to tomcat timeout.and server is not able to start.

How to solve this problem.

Similar questions were asked before , i went through them but i am not able to get the solution.

Please help

Comment: Please check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993493/error-servlet-jar-not-loaded . This might help you.

Comment: Can you post your tomcat version and eclipse version. So, we can better help you. Also, if you could post some of the things you have tried based on reading other sites so people would give you those answers as a solution to this problem.

Comment: tomcat 7 and Juno Service Release 1 I am using.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your project contains the Servlet API classes which are also provided by Tomcat.
If you are using Maven, set or manage the scope of the dependency to geronimo-servlet and set it to `<scope>provided</scope>`. If you are not, remove the Jar and  declare your project as a web project which will link the Java EE libraries to your project while excluding them from the deployment

Comment: remove the jar from where ?

Comment: @SaurabhSinha Are you using Maven or not?

Comment: Check that you have not the `geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar` file in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory. Or look at project build path configuration, in `Order and Export` if this Jar is not declared as exported.