# Servlet api not loaded in tomcat plug-in

Tags: maven, tomcat, servlets, maven-3, embedded-tomcat-7

I tried to deploy an Spring application on tomcat7 through tomcat7-maven-plugin (tomcat7:deploy), but when to execute the application, I get this error :

> INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\MyApp\WEB-
>   INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5-6.1.11.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spe
>   c 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
>   16-gen-2014 14.18.25 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal GRAVE: Error listenerStart 16-gen-2014 14.18.25
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal GRAVE: Context
>   [/MyApp] startup failed due to previous errors

while if I use jetty through jetty:run everything works.

This is my plugins configuration

```
        <!-- To launch embded jetty server -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jetty-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <!-- To launch embded tomcat server -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8081/manager/text</url>
                <server>my-tomcat</server>
                <path>/MyApp</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

while these are my dependencies:

```
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

 <!-- default j2ee dependencies  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are there any more errors in the `catalina.out`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Servlet Jar not Loaded... Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993493/error-servlet-jar-not-loaded-offending-class-javax-servlet-servlet-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the important part of the error message is

`INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\MyApp\WEB- INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5-6.1.11.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spe c 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class`

This means that you're trying to load `servlet-api-2.5-6.1.11.jar` as part of a web application which contains the definition of `javax.servlet.Servlet`. Section 9.7.2 of the mentioned specification states that the classloader which the container uses to load servlets **must not allow** the WAR to override J2SE or Java servlet API classes.

---

In my case I managed to exclude certain jars when building the war file with the following lines in the `pom.xml` file:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1-alpha-2</version>
  <configuration>
  ...
    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
  ...
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```