# What should I do for this NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: apache, tomcat, struts2, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

```
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\smart\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ konzernauto1\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Feb 10, 2014 12:40:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/FileManagerProvider
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_FileManager(Dispatcher.java:352)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:481)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4746)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.FileManagerProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Seems like a required class is missing .. "FileManagerProvider".

Comment: jar files are missing make sure you have included all the jar fiels of proper version

Comment: i ve added all the required jar files. Changed their versions and checked. Still the same error

Comment: Please use a meaningful title.

Comment: You are missing a dependency, just like the error states. Also, you must not deploy your own servlet api jar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Servlet Jar not Loaded... Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993493/error-servlet-jar-not-loaded-offending-class-javax-servlet-servlet-class)

Answer (score 0):

The INFO message simple tells you that Tomcat did not load the Servlet API from your app because it exists twice or its not the correct version. The SEVERE message tells you that you are missing a class in your classpath (NoClassDefFoundError). The class is called FileManagerProvider an is included in "xwork-core.jar".