# Jar file failed to load in tomcat webapps

Tags: java, jar, tomcat7, maven-3

This is what the error i got when i try to deploy maven project to tomcat

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

Error :

```sh
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\Softwares\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\myWebApp_
1\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.
0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

But the javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar is there in WEB-INF\lib
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Servlet Jar not Loaded... Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993493/error-servlet-jar-not-loaded-offending-class-javax-servlet-servlet-class)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> INFO: validateJarFile(D:\Softwares\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\myWebApp_ 1\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded

Servlet3.0 is already shipped with the tomcat inside its lib folder and by default tomcat will always load the servlet jar present there. Thats why you are getting the warning that tomcat is not loading your jar inside the project.

Simple solution : If you are using maven, set its scope as `provided` inside the pom.xml and maven will not place it in the WEB-INF/lib of your project. Something like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What if I am not using maven (Eclipse + terminal launched Tomcat) ?

Comment: If you aren't using maven, then you must have packaged the `servlet-api` jar inside the WEB-INF/lib folder of the war. Check the lib folder to verify and remove it if it is present there.

Comment: That helped, thanks but I have found out that while importing my project from SVN I can see that Apache CXF being in the dependencies of  my project has a `geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar` dependency and it is being packaged to the `lib/` directory of my `.war`. Any ideas how to remove it from there ?

Comment: I can't properly recall if I was getting this warning when I was working on cxf but are you getting the `jar not loaded` warning for this particular 'geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar' as well in the tomcat logs? If yes, you always have the option to unpack the cxf jar and remove the servlet_spec jar from it and then re-pack it.

Comment: cxf jar does not contain any servlet jar. There is `geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar` but in the dir next to cxf .jar. If I remove it then I cannot create `.war` from my app.

Comment: I see.. can you post a new question for this so that it can be investigated independantly.

Comment: Done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849471/apache-cxf-geronimo-servlet-3-0-spec-1-0-jar-jar-not-loaded-having-tomcats-se

Comment: after search a lot I got answer and very helpful for me.

Comment: You need to add `<version>3.0.1</version>` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855531/how-to-config-maven-to-use-servlet-3) post.

Answer (score 2):

Precise explanation by Saif asif.

I was using gradle as the build tool. It worked for me to exclude the tomcat-servlet-api.jar which is by default provided by tomcat.

You need to know which of your dependency is transitively adding tomcat-servlet-api.jar to the war and then exclude it using following

```
 compile ('your dependency goes here') {
        exclude module:'tomcat-servlet-api'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an warning that appears in your log, not an error. Your project will still deploy if you ignore this.

You can get get rid of this error by rebuilding your .war using maven and copying it into \webapps\ removing your old files.

Answer (score -2):

Best Solution : remove that jar(i.e javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) from lib