# Apache CXF geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar - jar not loaded having Tomcat's servlet jar

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jar, cxf

I am having a problem where I have Apache CXF jar included in my project (I use Eclipse as IDE) and after running Tomcat I get the following:

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/USER/programming/tools/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/webapps/abosi/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

This is because Apache CXF is deploying `geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar` as a part of the app to `WEB_INF/lib` directory but Tomcat already has it's servlet implementation in `TOMCAT_ROOT/./lib/servlet-api.jar`.

How can I prevent this ?

Comment: Can you mention what problem you got when you tried to remove it from the cxf jar ?

Comment: It is not in the CXF jar. It is in the lib folder of CXF library ( If I remove it from there I won't be able to load my application in tomcat.)

Answer (score 4):

You can rid this message by explicitly excluding the geronimo jar in your pom.xml like so:

```
    ....
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-milestone2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    ....
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this issue by removing Apache CXF from **Order and export** tab in `Project Properties` -> `Java Build Path`

[image]

and removing the `.jar`s from `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/APP_NAME/lib/geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar` and `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/abosi/WEB-INF/lib/activemq-all-5.9.0.jar`

**EDIT**

After trying it out and deploying few times it appeared that this is **NOT** a solution. Those `.jars` are still appearing in this directory. Any ideas ?

Comment: If the application is having servlets based on 2.3 or 2.5 and the jar file is missing in the respective wars add them and deploy.  removing the servlet-api.jar from tomcat 7/lib folder will not allow tomcat to start up.