# jar not loaded, i am using eclipse IDE

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

INFO: validateJarFile(E:\JavaProjectPractic.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\KKWebSite\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Comment: You'll have to add more information about the issue you are seeing so we can properly diagnose it.

Comment: i am doing it simply with jsp servlet. if i delete servlet api from lib it generates error in my servlet page,

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993493/error-servlet-jar-not-loaded-offending-class-javax-servlet-servlet-class

Answer (score 2):

You should not put `servlet-api.jar` in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your web application. The Servlet API is supplied by the servlet container.

Remove `servlet-api.jar` from the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your web application.

If your project is a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) project and you have a dependency on `servlet-api.jar`, then set the scope of the dependency to `provided`. An example of how that would look in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: nope i am doing it simply with jsp servlet, and if i remove the servlet-api it shows error in my servlet in extends

Comment: You need `servlet-api.jar` in the classpath when you **compile** the project, but you must not have it in there when you run it in a servlet container.

Comment: can u please explain it more.. cause i m having this problem so many time when i starts my new project in eclipse.